# Firth penalized regression

Tags: r, statistics, logistic-regression, logistf

I'm modelling a logistic regression with the Firth's correction, using `logistf` package in R. When I use the command `DROP1`/`ADD1`, R help says it is based on the penalized likelihood ratio. But is the penalization it says actually the Firth's correction or is it just a penalized likelihood?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The package description says: Firth's bias reduced logistic regression approach with penalized profile likelihood based confidence intervals for
parameter estimates. So I guess the parameters are estimated with the Firth's correction, but the confidence intervals are estimated with penalized likelihood.

Comment: i already figured it out, but thanks :)